# How do I get the Googlebot to index our dynamically generated Lightning community pages?

Tags: community, lightning, google, seo

We have a lightning community with all dynamically generated content for our faculty profiles. Information on the profile comes from SF, so there's nothing static on the page. As a result, the Googlebot is not seeing much of anything on the pages. Even though all the pages have been crawled, none was indexed. :(

Anyone have any ideas? Apparently Google does index dynamic pages, but only if there are static content on the page as well as dynamic ones.

Comment: If it's all dynamic, what do you even want googlebot to find? The only thing I can think of is to add a description tag in the head like in the good ol days. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

Comment: that, unfortunately, is kind of the problem. SF doesn't let you put dynamic content into the <title> tag, since it's controlled in Builder.

Comment: I didn't say title, I said description. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/community_builder_page_head.htm You also failed to answer the first question, what is it you expect google to find on a dynamic page? If I were using google to find your page, what do you think it should look like in the search results?

Comment: Description will have to be different for each page. What we expect them to see if bio, publications, research, and much more, filled in by the faculty themselves. So the data changes. I want them to simply index the page at this point, but no luck.

Comment: If it's a dynamic page your description does not change for every page. The page's description is "360 degree view of the specified contact" the content of the page might change but the pages purpose does not. There is no way for google to index all potential variations of the page, That would require google bot to log in as specified users and pass any/all possible URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the [communities setup guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/communities.pdf) you will find pretty much every reason in regards to why and how to get your community content indexed by google. More specifically, pages 61-65.

> If you created a detail page for the object and enabled the object’s
>   “Read” permission on the guest user profile, the URL for the detail
>   page is included in the site map. However, URLs for the list and
>   related list pages aren’t included.

So, you might want to make sure that these pages are included in your sitemap.
Try accessing `https://<community_URL>/s/sitemap.xml`  usning your browser in incognito mode, this will basically point you towards what google's crawler has access to.

For further details, i would strongly suggest you go through the guide for setting SEO for Communities from the above link.

Comment: So sitemap isn't an issue. We provided the sitemap already. It's the fact that crawling results in no details on the page, due to the fact that content is all dynamic. Community setup guide has nothing on that unfortunately. Been there, done that.